# Tensorflow GradientTape "Gradients does not exist for variables" intermittently

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When training my network I am occasionally met with the warning:

`W0722 11:47:35.101842 140641577297728 optimizer_v2.py:928] Gradients does not exist for variables ['model/conv1d_x/Variable:0'] when minimizing the loss.`

This happens sporadically at infrequent intervals (maybe once in every 20 successful steps). My model basically has two paths which join together with concatenations at various positions in the network. To illustrate this, here is a simplified example of what I mean.

```
class myModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):

    self.conv1 = Conv2D(32)
    self.conv2 = Conv2D(32)
    self.conv3 = Conv2D(16)

  def call(self, inputs):

    net1 = self.conv1(inputs)
    net2 = self.conv2(inputs)
    net = tf.concat([net1, net2], axis=2)
    net = self.conv3(net)
    end_points = tf.nn.softmax(net)

model = myModel()

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

  predicition = model(image)
  loss = myloss(labels, prediction)

gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

In reality my network is much larger, but the variables that generally don't have gradients tend to be the ones at the top of the network. Before each `Conv2D` layer I also have a custom gradient. Sometimes when I the error appears I can notice that the gradient function for that layer has not been called.

My question is how can the gradient tape sometimes take what appears to be different paths when propagating backwards through my network. My secondary question, is this caused by having two separate routes through my network (i.e. conv1 AND conv2). Is there a fundamental flaw in this network architecture?

Ideally, could I define to the `GradientTape()` that it must find the gradients for each of the top layers?

Comment: Hi D.Griffiths, 
With the code specified by you and the explanation given by you, we couldn't reproduce your error. Can you please share complete code (Dummy code, which represents your architecture and Custom Gradients should suffice), so that we can try reproducing the error and work towards its resolution. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, the code to reproduce the issue would be my whole network which is rather large and contains custom ops and specific data etc. I don't believe this is a bug with the TF code. I was more wandering in what scenarios would gradients not exists for certain variables intermittently causing the error to be thrown. For example is it normal that maybe a division by zero occurs, or is this something I should be worried about (and even a bug from my end).

Comment: Is it still happening?

Comment: I just had a similar problem where I was always getting the warning. My code was different. Basically, in the build function of the custom class, I was adding a weight and overwriting my reference to it. By avoiding that the warning went away. But your case doesn't seem to be similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revisiting this question, it is actually quite unhelpful and probably should have been down voted more! There are many scenarios where your gradient has invalid values in it. But ultimately, at some point in the gradient computation a `NaN` value was created.

In my scenario I was using custom gradient op, and ultimately there was a bug in my gradient calculation code. This bug caused the `NaN` under some circumstances.

If you are not using custom gradient ops, then likely you've either made a mistake in your network definition (e.g., disconnected variable as other answers suggest) or there is some issue with your data.

In summary, no *one* problem will cause this, it just an artefact from a) buggy gradient calculation, b) buggy network definition, c) issue with your data or d) anything else. There is no *one* solution for this question, it's just the result of an error somewhere else.

To directly answer my questions in the original post:

Q. How can the gradient tape sometimes take what appears to be different paths when propagating backwards through my network?

A. It doesn't, a bug in the input to the gradient function resulted in no gradients being calcucated for that layer.

Q. My secondary question, is this caused by having two separate routes through my network (i.e. conv1 AND conv2). Is there a fundamental flaw in this network architecture?

A. No, there is nothing wrong with this architecture.

Answer (score 26):

The solution given by Nguyễn and gkennos will suppress the error because it would replace all `None` by zeros.
However, it is a big issue that your gradient is null at any point in time.
The problem described above is certainly caused by `unconnected variables` (by default PyTorch will throw runtime error).

The most common case of unconnected layers can be exemplify as follow:

```
 def some_func(x):
       x1 = x * some variables
       x2 = x1 + some variables #x2 discontinued after here
       x3 = x1 / some variables
       return x3
```

Now observe that `x2` is unconnected, so gradient will not be propagated throw it. Carefully debug your code for unconnected variables.

Comment: This is the right answer, and should be upvoted more. Suppressing the error with `None`'s is like hiding the head under the sand pretending the problem doesn't exist.

Comment: Agree with @Leevo, this should be upvoted more.  Solved my issue perfectly.

Answer (score 17):

I had an issue that seems similar - may be helpful or not sure depending on what your network actually looks like, but basically, I had a multi-output network and I realised that as I was applying gradients that corresponded to the outputs separately, so for each separate loss there was a branch of the network for which the gradient was zero, but this was totally valid and corresponded to the terminal layers immediately prior to the non-targeted outputs each time.  For this reason, I ended up replacing any None gradients with tf.zeros_like and it was possible to proceed with training.  Could you have the same problem with multiple input heads to your network, if it's always at the top of the graph?

(ETA solution by Nguyễn Thu below is the code version of what I'm describing in above - exactly the same way that I dealt with it)

I've seen other answers where gradients weren't calculating because tensors aren't watched by default - you have to add them, but looks like that's not your issue as you should be only dealing with model.trainable_variables, or perhaps your myLoss function is getting a NaN result or casting to a numpy array occasionally depending on your batch composition, which would explain the sporadic nature (e.g. perhaps it's on batches that have no instances of a minority class if your data is very imbalanced?)

Comment: plus 1; the problem with my loss function is indeed my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If missing gradients are expected, this warning can be suppressed by [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60217922/4960855):

```
optimizer.apply_gradients(
    (grad, var) 
    for (grad, var) in zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables) 
    if grad is not None
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Gradient tape's `gradient` method has a `unconnected_gradients` parameter that allows you to specify whether unconnected gradients should be **None** or **Zero**. See docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#gradient

So you could change the line:

```
gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
```

to

```
gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables, 
                unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO)
```

This worked for me.

**EDIT - IMPORTANT**: This is only a solution if you actually expect some gradients to be zero. This is NOT a solution if the error results from a broken backpropagation. In that case you will need to find and fix where it is broken.

Comment: Can confirm. this works for me aswell.. TF2.5

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Found the solution with customized gradients

```
  def _compute_gradients(tensor, var_list):
      grads = tf.gradients(tensor, var_list)
  return [grad if grad is not None else tf.zeros_like(var)
      for var, grad in zip(var_list, grads)]
```

from [github trouble shoot](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/783)

Comment: where would this be added?

Answer (score 2):

I also encoutered the same error. It was because I gave the wrong trainable variables in `tape.gradient()` function. If it can help someone.

In my example `self.encoder_model.get_trainable_variables()` was not returning the good variables:

```
@tf.function
def train_step(x_batch):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = self.encoder_model.loss.compute_loss(x_batch)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.encoder_model.get_trainable_variables())
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.encoder_model.get_trainable_variables()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same issue, and though my case is quite peculiar, still it can help someone out.

I trained a network model_1 and then defined it as a layer in model_2.

So I had

```
class Model_2(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, n, iter):
        super().__init__()
        ...layers defined...
        self.extra_layer = model_1
```

Eventually I forgot about presence of the self.extra_layer in my network (as it turned out to be useless) and were training model_2 without this layer. Tensorflow threw warnings which basically said that layers inside model_1 weren't connected to the global graph, however it seemed like the problem had something to do with model_2.

Answer (score -1):

there are no gradients because the variable doesn't affect the answer.
in this code, the call function is missing a **return**

```
class myModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):

    self.conv1 = Conv2D(32)
    self.conv2 = Conv2D(32)
    self.conv3 = Conv2D(16)

  def call(self, inputs):

    net1 = self.conv1(inputs)
    net2 = self.conv2(inputs)
    net = tf.concat([net1, net2], axis=2)
    net = self.conv3(net)
    return end_points = tf.nn.softmax(net)  # Change this line
```