# How to suppress specific warning in Tensorflow (Python)

Tags: python, tensorflow, warnings, tensorflow2.0, suppress-warnings

I have a model that, based on certain conditions, has some unconnected gradients, and this is exactly what I want. But Tensorflow is printing out a Warning every time it encounters the unconnected gradient.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables
```

Is there any way to only suppress this specific warning? I don't want to blindly suppress all warnings since there might be unexpected (and potentially useful) warnings in the future as I'm still working on my model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kinda hacky way:

```
gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients([
    (grad, var) 
    for (grad, var) in zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables) 
    if grad is not None
])
```

Comment: `apply_gradients` accepts iterators too (like `zip`), so your code also works without the `[ ]` that turns the generator expression into a list comprehension.