# Suppression of Tensorflow Warning

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a tensorflow 2.x functional model model whose first layers are from another pretrained model.  I want those layers to remain frozen, so I have used `tf.stop_gradient` on the pretrained head to stop them from learning.  Below is a minimal example of my network:

```
head =  load_my_cool_pretrained_representation_model()
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10000)(tf.stop_gradient(head.output))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=head.inputs, outputs=x)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
```

When I use `model.fit()` I get the following warning:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['cool_rep_layer/embeddings:0', ...] when minimizing the loss.

I do not need the warning as I want those layers to not have gradients.  How can I suppress this warning?  I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60022462/how-to-suppress-specific-warning-in-tensorflow-python), but I do not want to get into gradient tape for this model.

Comment: try this
`logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [noober's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17011524/noober) comment, I just added

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

to get rid of the warnings.  This worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me, tf 2.5

Comment: Can you use this before or after importing tensorflow?